# Erlaubnis um eine Musikmarke bekommen

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verb-choice

> Wie habt ihr Erlaubnis um eine Musikmarke bekommen?

How did you get a permission for a Music Label ?

I am not sure if the words "Erlaubnis" and "Musikmarke" are correct in this context. i am not sure about the verb "bekommen" either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

> Wie habt ihr die Lizenz für ein Musiklabel bekommen?

"Bekommen" is fine. "Erlaubnis" is maybe a bit more "permissionary" in German than it is in English. If I want to start a label I'll just do it. My mom can give me permission. Government can only give me licenses or registrations or recognitions or whatever other legal term. In either case, it would be connected to its object using "für".

As for label.. it is definitely "Label" in German as well, by now. There used to be "(Musik)verlag" but that reduced its meaning to "the company publishing the score".

Comment: Since you suggested a translation of the sentence “How did you get a permission for a Music Label?”, I assume that you understood its meaning? I didn't. Neither would I know what a „Lizenz für ein Musiklabel“ is. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, in general the state does grant „Erlaubnisse“: Arbeitserlaubnis, Aufenthaltserlaubnis.